# Flickering while repainting the custom form

Tags: c#, forms

I have derived a class from **System.Windows.Forms.Form** class to create a custom form.

I have override the method **WndProc(ref m)** and process **WM_NCPAINT** window message to draw the caption bar with my own customizations.

I have drawn the caption bar, buttons and icon by using Graphics methods.

The problem with this is, resizing the form causes the form's non client areas to repaint which leads to flickering in the non client areas.

I have tried overriding the CreateParams and setting double buffering to true. But I don't know how to use these things correctly.

Can you please provide solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to set double buffering and override `CreateParams` for the control that is causing the problem. If that's the `Button` then set those for that particular button class ( extend it or something ).

Comment: @m.rogalski Thanks for your response. I'll try this. But the problem is not only in the controls. The title bar itself flickers while resizing the form. Flickering occurs in the border lines, title bar buttons and in the icon.

Comment: Can you somehow show how it behaves? Make a video clip or gif?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit the question.

Comment: This has been unpractical for 16 years already, visual styles killed it off.  The basic reason why everybody uses a borderless window to emulate custom chrome.